# java: Good socket timeout for LAN connections?

Tags: java, android, sockets, timeout

I have a server (java app running on my laptop) and a client (java app running on my android smartphone).
I'm trying to **automatically find the IP address of the server from my client**.

Right now i just loop all IPs in the same LAN (192.168.1.0 > 192.168.1.1.255) and if the server (that is listening on a custom port) accept the connection then i found the IP.

**The problem is, if i set the connection timeout less then 200ms most of times the client can't find the server.**

So the question is, how i can implement a better (faster) way to find the server IP?
I have tried the java InetAddress.isReachable() method but the server always seems unrechable...

And, if there isn't a better way, what do you think it's a good timeout value from local (LAN) socket connections?

Comment: You might want to look into Network Service Discovery - http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for others... I just found a very good way to find the server IP in LESS THEN HALF SECOND!

here my solution:

```
String partialIp = "192.168.1.";
int port = 123;
int counter;
boolean found;
String ip;

Runnable tryNextIp = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int myIp = counter++;
        String targetIpTemp = partialIp + myIp;
        Socket socketTemp = new Socket();
        try {           
            socketTemp.connect(new InetSocketAddress(targetIpTemp, port), 6000);
            socketTemp.close();
            ip = targetIpTemp;
            found = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {               
            try {
                socketTemp.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {}
        }
    }
};

String findIp() {
    counter = 0;
    found = false;

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(256);
    for (int i=0; i<256; i++) {
        if (found)
            break;
        executorService.execute(tryNextIp);
    }           
    executorService.shutdown();
    try {
        while (!found && !executorService.isTerminated())
            executorService.awaitTermination(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);               
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    if (found)
        return ip;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good timeout value is the time you're willing to wait for your server to reply, given typical network conditions and server response times. You need to pick a reasonable value, independently of your application here -- it is up to you to decide that if the server does not respond in X amount of time, then it is safe to assume it is not there.

To speed up your client, consider creating multiple threads to query multiple servers at once. [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) will make this trivial for you.

However, you may want to consider other alternatives that don't require a full network scan; for example:

- Just let the user/administrator specify the IP address (*Why* do you need to discover the server IP? Do you not know what machine you set up your server on? Why not just configure the server to have a static LAN IP?)
- If you truly do need service discovery, technologies like NSD/Zeroconf/Bonjour allow for service advertising and discovery.
- Even something very basic may be suitable to your needs, e.g. send a broadcast UDP packet from the client and let the server respond, or have the server periodically broadcast announcements.

Comment: many thanks for your reply! I think that **for my needs** the best solution is to query multiple servers at once! I will search more info about threadpool, thanks again!

Comment: @user2104749 You'll find that thread pool solution to be very easy, then. Check out [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html); after creating a fixed thread pool executor, you essentially create one `Runnable` or `Callable` for each of your server queries, throw them all in the queue, and wait for them to finish. Higher max thread count = potentially faster complete scans but higher resource usage; you'll want to find a balance.

Comment: man i just tried it it's BLAZING FAST! incredible :D i can find the server ip in less then 2 seconds, many thanks!

Comment: last question... Do you think it's safe to set the maximum threads number to 255 (every thread just open a socket and read the response) in an android device or it's too much work to handle for a smartphone?

Answer (score 0):

What the socket timeout should be depends entirely on the expected service time of the request. Naively you could find the average service time and use double that for the timeout. If you want to get more accurate, you would need to plot the statistical distribution of service times, determine the standard deviation, and use the average plus three or even four times the standard deviation as the timeout, to make sure you don't get false-positive timeouts but you do detect failures within a reasonable time. Ultimately it depends on just how trigger-happy you want to be.